# Swift programmatic UI UIContextMenuInteraction Auto layout error (groupView) on opening context menu

Tags: autolayout, constraints, swift5, uicontextmenuinteraction

I have an app with a programmatic UI (No storyboards). I add a context menu to a button of my viewcontroller. On opening this menu (tap and hold on the button) I get a LayoutConstraints warning/error in the console (menu works fine otherwise:

```
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600001c9ed50 h=--& v=--& UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x7f9d4478ceb0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001cd7c50 groupView.actionsSequence....height >= 66   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x7f9d4610ee00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001cb3de0 UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x7f9d4478ceb0.top == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x7f9d4478bba0''.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001cb3e80 V:[_UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x7f9d4478bba0'']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIInterfaceActionGroupView:0x7f9d4478ceb0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001cad090 groupView.actionsSequence....top == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x7f9d4478bba0''.top   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x7f9d4610ee00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001cad130 groupView.actionsSequence....bottom == _UIContentConstraintsLayoutGuide:0x7f9d4478bba0''.bottom   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x7f9d4610ee00 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001cd7c50 groupView.actionsSequence....height >= 66   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x7f9d4610ee00 )>
```

this **groupView** is not a view of mine! I have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on all my custom controls (labels, fields, etc). I presume I need to set that to for the context menu somewhere, but I don't know how or where.

Relevant code:

In my viewcontroller:

```
        let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
        annotationTypeButton.addInteraction(interaction)
```

Delegate extension:

```
//MARK: - UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate
extension AnnotationDetailsViewController: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: "annotationTypeMenu" as NSCopying, previewProvider: nil) { _ in
            let children: [UIMenuElement] = self.makeAnnotationTypeActions()
            return UIMenu(title: "", children: children)
        }
    }
    
    func makeAnnotationTypeActions() -> [UIAction] {
        var actions = [UIAction]()
        for type in AnnotationType.allCases {
            actions.append( UIAction(title: type.rawValue, image: type.image, identifier: nil, attributes: []) { _ in
                let annotationType = AnnotationType(rawValue: type.rawValue) ?? AnnotationType.tips
                self.annotation.type = annotationType
                self.configureAnnotationTypeButton(with: annotationType)
            })
        }
        return actions
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on the Apple developer forums saying that **the layout warning is a known issue and will be solved in iOS14**!

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652622?login=true&page=1#618265022